# Why is this result "0" in my Java app?

Tags: java, floating-point

I tried the following operation :

```
728660000f-728659968f
```

Which is a minus operation in float, and it ends up as "0", why ?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://ideone.com/PWQtFV)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those two values can't be represented exactly as single-precision floats, and the approximations made when converting them from integers result in the two having the same value.  Therefore, subtracting them yields 0.

Comment: The approximation being 7.2865997E8

Comment: @EdwardM.B. `728659968f`, actually. Certainly not `7.2865997E8`,  which is a `double` with the value 728659970, although you could say that the approximation is `728660000f` or `728659970f`, since both these representations correspond to the same single-precision number.